# Why does document.onmousemove happen even when the mouse doesn't move?

Tags: javascript, events, mouse, onmousemove

I'm new to javascript and trying some code that I got from CodeLifter.com for [capturing the XY position of the mouse](http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/capturemouseposition1.html). I've modified the code so that each time the mousemove function is called my function will append the coordinates to a textarea. What I've noticed in IE9 and Chrome 26 is that even when the mouse cursor isn't moving if it's in the browser window it will just show the same coordinates again and again. That doesn't happen in Firefox though.

For example here is me moving the mouse in Chrome and notice the same coordinates are repeated again and again when the mouse becomes stationary:

```
77, 328
80, 365
82, 388
82, 400
84, 412
84, 413
35, 306
25, 258
25, 255
25, 255
25, 255
25, 255
```

So 25, 255 is the coordinate when I stopped moving the mouse. It's just repeated over and over again, which means onmousemove is being called over and over again even though the mouse isn't moving. Why is that? I put the webpage I made online [here](http://test0523.zxq.net/mousemon.html) so you can see what I mean.

Thanks

Comment: Your demo page is working for me on Firefox too. Can you post your code?

Comment: @Kishor the code is in the html page. if you view the source of the page you'll see the code. I didn't want to post the whole page here it would clutter things.

Comment: Check the answer below. But it will be a good practice if you paste your code here too or create a demo fiddle at [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: One thing I noticed that it happens only when the mouse is on the textarea.

Comment: I notice that coordinates only start to repeat if the mouse is stationary over the textArea after that textArea became scrolled, at least in Chrome.

Comment: @gfcarv: Exactly. Looks like the when the text is added to the text area hence scrolled to bottom, then this scrolling is firing the event. I wonder if it is possible.

Comment: Also using the `e.preventDefault` stops this issue.

Comment: I believe when the textArea is scrolled to bottom with mouse over it, the mouse position over the textArea element will be different each time the scroll bar goes down. And for this reason browser fires the event. And @Digvijay `e.preventDefault` don't seems to stop this issue.

Comment: @gfcarv: Try to put the `e.prevent....` after getting the `tempX` and `tempY` values. Somehow its working on my system.